# File uploading in IE with umlauts in filename

Tags: php, internet-explorer, file-upload

I have this file upload and it works in Firefox fine, but when I upload file n IE and filename has umlauts, then filename is corrupted. After file is uploaded I echo filename and filename is corrupted like in my example.

Example:

ä.png is converted to Ã¤.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just the encoding which don't match, try

```
echo utf8_decode($filename);
```

Comment: Thanx it worked, but only in cases when browser cannot handle it on it own. So i had to add ie version check to my script too.

Comment: Or you can change your pages encoding for UTF8 ^^